# Algorithm Divisible Sum Pairs

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I did the [Divisible Sum Pairs problem on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/divisible-sum-pairs/problem)

> input: *n* is length of array *ar*, *k* is an integer value.
>   a pair is define only if *ar*[*i*]+*ar*[*j*] is dividable by *k* where *i* < *j*.
>   Problem: find and return pairs in array.

```
def divisibleSumPairs(n, k, ar):
    i=0       #pointer 1
    j=1       #pointer 2 is faster than p1  
    count =0  #pointer 3 will only increment 1 once j = n-1 (second last element)
    pairs=0
    while count < n-1:
        if (ar[i]+ar[j])%k==0: 
            pairs+=1
        j+=1
        count+=1
        if count==n-1:
            i+=1
            j=i+1
            count =i
    print(pairs)
```

Code visualized

```
step 1:
 i  j
[a][b][c][e][f]
compare (i,j)
 i     j
[a][b][c][e][f]
compare (i,j)
 i        j
[a][b][c][e][f]
compare (i,j)
 i           j
[a][b][c][e][f]
compare (i,j)
i+=1
j=i+1

step2
    i  j
[a][b][c][e][f]
compare (i,j)
        .
        .
        .
        .
step n
          i  j
[a][b][c][e][f]
compare (i,j)
finish
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. Does this algorithm have a name?
2. Is there other way (maybe better, faster)?
3. Is there some code I could have done better/ differently?

`#some test  data n=6 , k=3 ar =[1, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2]`

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. Did you check the discussions on HackerRank for this challenge? There is a decent solution posted there with explanation. You can find it [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/divisible-sum-pairs/forum/comments/152302)

Comment: Thanks @impopularGuy. I did. However, the top voted code, written by usinha02, is stated to be O(n) time complexity. I don't understand how this can be when the code is using nested for loops? Shouldn't it then be O(n^2) time complexity? I guess it has something to do with the way the array is split into buckets of k  i%k  where i= 0,1,..k divide and conquer -ish?

Comment: I agree that the one I linked is not O(n) but is rather O(nk). However have a look at an [explanation](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/divisible-sum-pairs/forum/comments/153278) and the [python implementation](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/divisible-sum-pairs/forum/comments/242851)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not Pythonic as it does not adhere to the standard Python style guide.

1. `divisibleSumPairs` should be snake case `divisible_sum_pairs`.
2. You should have one space both sides of most operators. `i=0` `i+=1`, `ar[i]+ar[j]` are all harder to read than they need to be.
3. Most of your variable names don't describe what they contain.
4. You `print` inside a function that should `return`.

```py
def divisible_sum_pairs(length, divisor, items):
    i = 0       #pointer 1
    j = 1       #pointer 2 is faster than p1
    count = 0   #pointer 3 will only increment 1 once j = n-1 (second last element)
    pairs = 0
    while count < length - 1:
        if (items[i] + items[j]) % divisor == 0: 
            pairs += 1
        j += 1
        count += 1
        if count == length - 1:
            i += 1
            j = i + 1
            count = i
    return pairs
```

5. You don't need pointer 3 as `count = j + 1`:

   ```py
   j += 1
   count += 1
   ```

   ```py
   j = i + 1
   count = i
   ```

   We can just replace `count` with `j - 1`.
6. We can simplify all of the places where `count` was being used.
   This is as you have `- 1`s  on both sides of the operators.
7. Rather than `while j < length` it would be clearer if you instead used `while i < length - 1`.
   This comes in two parts:

   - It is confusing to see `while j < length` with `if j == length` in the body.
   - You're not actually bound by `j` you're bound by `i`.
8. Rather than using a `while` loop we can see that there's an opportunity to use two for loops to make things easier to read.

   **Note**: These for loops have the exact same time complexity as your `while`.

```py
def divisible_sum_pairs(length, divisor, items):
    pairs = 0
    for i in range(length - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, length):
            if (items[i] + items[j]) % divisor == 0: 
                pairs += 1
    return pairs
```

9. We can simplify the code by using using a comprehension.

   For example we can extract getting the combinations of items.

   ```py
   combinations = (
       (items[i], items[j])
       for i in range(length - 1)
       for j in range(i + 1, length)
   )
   for a, b in combinations:
       if (a + b) % divisor == 0:
   ```
10. We can instead `sum` with a comprehension that generates numbers.

    ```py
    pairs = sum(
        1
        for a, b in combinations
        if (a + b) % divisor == 0
    )
    ```
11. We can exploit the fact that bools are integers and move the if's expression as the comprehension's expression.
12. We can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to remove the need to manually get the combinations.

```py
import itertools


def divisible_sum_pairs(_, divisor, items):
    return sum(
        (a + b) % divisor == 0
        for a, b in itertools.combinations(items, 2)
    )
```

Every change has been a 1 to 1 replacement. The time complexity is still \$O(\binom{n}{2})\$ (\$O(n^2)\$) and memory complexity is still \$O(1)\$.

However now readability is much better.

Comment: nice answer. Only remark I have is that instead of the `for i in range(length - 1)` in the intermediate solution, I would introduce `enumerate` here.

Comment: @MaartenFabré I had thought of using `enumerate` but getting all bar the last value with it is not really that clean.